# Error SED syntax: unknown command: `0'

Tags: linux, sed

I want to parse this string:

```
Decimal: 999/581
```

I want get this: 999/581

I use this command:

```
sed -e '\[0-9]\+/[0-9]\+'
```

And get error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown command: `0'
```

What's wrong?

Comment: did you want to get this `999/581`?

Comment: You are getting "unknown command: `0'" because the forward slash was not escaped. To solve the other problems, it would be helpful if you explained what, precisely, you are trying to accomplish.  What is your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `sed -e '\[0-9]\+/[0-9]\+'` you get "unknown command" error because that's not a valid `sed` command. For example I used the `s///` command in the above examples. In your post there's nothing that looks like a `sed` command.

Maybe you're looking for this:

```
echo 'Decimal: 999/581' | sed -e 's/[^0-9]*//'
```

or this:

```
echo 'Decimal: 999/581' | sed -e 's/Decimal: //'
```